# Does dubbo thread model init the fixed number of threads at start time?

Tags: java, apache-dubbo

A part of my dubbo configuration file:

```
<dubbo:protocol name="dubbo" dispatcher="all" threadpool="fixed" threads="100" />
```

According to dubbo documentation the config above means

> A fixed size of thread pool and it creates threads when starts, never shut down.

But when I started the application then I use `jstack` to see if there are more than 100 threads, I found only about 40 threads and I didn't find any dubbo threads. So, what happened?

Answer (score 1):

The [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) that you create by declaring `dubbo:protocol` is not the only source of threads in the JVM. Normally JVM starts a number of utility threads so it can function properly and support various features e.g. finalizers, shutdown hooks, RMI, etc. `jstack` shows the thread names, most of them you should be able to google and understand their purpose.

Your `dubbo` thread pool will most likely spawn new threads only when handling the incoming requests.

Comment: I've used dubbo consumer to test already, and I didn't see any the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Here's dubbo thread model(http://dubbo.apache.org/en-us/docs/user/demos/thread-model.html),there is a picture demonstrating dubbo thread model,you can see that only server has a thread pool,which means only dubbo provider has thread pool.because it needs to separate I/O thread from non I/O thread.